# Accessing OpenLayers on "Manage and Install Plugins"

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am a new QGIS user and I am trying to add the OpenLayers plugins.  I went into 'Manage and Install Plugins', and made sure I had the 'All' tab selected.  However, whenever I try to search for the pluggin, it never shows up as on option.  In the dialog box I wrote out 'OpenLayers'.  Other plugins show up, but not that one.

Comment: If you're using 2.4, the OpenLayers plugin isn't yet available for this new release: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10770

Comment: It is by now: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/version/1.3.3/